# PHP Access object property from CI result object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my code, I'm searching the table names which ends with keyword called '_countries'.

I'm getting a result also but I do not know how to get table name from that result.

This is the code the fetches the query result:

```
$sql="show tables like '%_countries'";
$result=$this->db->query($sql);
foreach ($result -> result() as $delete) {
    print_r( $delete);
}
```

The `print_r()`'s result is:

```
stdClass Object ( [Tables_in_test (%_countries)] => news_countries )
```

`news_countries` is the result which I need.

This is how I'm trying to access the property inside the loop:

```
$delete->table_name;
$delete->name;
$delete->Tables_in_test;
```

But above codes did not give result I need.

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$table_name this error when i try with $delete->table_name;

Comment: weird property name, try `$delete->{'Tables_in_test (%_countries)'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try to use `reset()` in this case:

```
foreach ($result->result_array() as $delete) {
    $name = reset($delete);
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: it works like charm , and please upvote my question ,it will be useful for some other people

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam i think another way is selecting it thru `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, plus, you get to choose your own alias for that column name, i just can't test it since i don't have CI on my env, anyways,  glad this helped,

Comment: Okay , Thank you for your wonderful helping . i will try with INFORMATION_SCHEMA also

Comment: something like: `SELECT `TABLE_NAME` AS `table_name` FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_NAME` LIKE '%countries%'`